# Is it grammatically correct to say: "Running after the zebra, is a lion."

Tags: syntactic-analysis, word-order, sentence-patterns

Of course you can simply say:

`A lion is running after the zebra`

But I still like to know if it is grammatically correct to change the order like:

`Running after the zebra, is a lion.`

If so, do I need a comma in between like this?

Comment: You do not need the comma.  In fact, adding the comma tends to change the meaning to something like "The zebra will run the first lap, and a lion will run the second lap."

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a comma in this example.

Maybe if you were writing something like, `Running after the zebra, the lion tripped over a root`.